# about hawq pxf access file data on hdfs

Tags: postgresql, hadoop, hawq

After I deployed hdfs, map reduce, hawq, pxf with ambari, I have generated about 10G data on hdfs using impala-tpcds-kits.

But when I login in Postgres with the user postgres, I can't  use the command line `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` to index the data on hdfs. And when I use psql help command, there isn't the key word `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE`.

I don't know why?

```
Last login: Thu Aug 25 15:08:15 2016 from 192.168.1.50
[root@hadoop-m-21 ~]# su postgres
bash-4.1$ psql
psql (8.4.20)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EXT_LOG_INFO (hight int,weight int) 
LOCATION     ('pxf://10.0.0.21:51200/tmp/test2.txt?PROFILE=HdfsTextSimple') 
FORMAT 'TEXT' (DELIMITER '|'); 
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXTERNAL"
LINE 1: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE EXT_LOG_INFO (hight int,weight int) LO...
           ^
```

Comment: There is no such thing as `create external table` in Postgres. See the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html The help in `psql` only shows you the psql specific commands, not the help for SQL statements (and why are you using such an outdated and unsupported Postgres version?)

Comment: This version isn't I want to use . It is installed automaticly when I install hawq .

Comment: HAWQ isn't PostgreSQL.  I suggest you remove the postgresql tag so that people like a_horse_with_no_name doesn't get on his high horse (ha ha) and tell us how HAWQ commands don't work in PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't connecting to HAWQ.

```
[root@hadoop-m-21 ~]# su postgres
bash-4.1$ psql
psql (8.4.20)
Type "help" for help.
```

This is a PostgreSQL database and likely the database installed for Ambari.  Use the gpadmin account instead of postgres.

Also, if you are wanting to run TPC-DS, try this one instead which is designed for HAWQ and Greenplum.  https://github.com/pivotalguru/TPC-DS

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you are calling psql which connect to hawq, instead of connecting to linux built-in postgreSQL instance.

You can run 'netstat -anp | grep 5432' to know the pid of postgres, and use 'ps -ef | grep your_pid to know the binary path, check the path is hawq.

Or you can run SQL 'SELECT VERSION();' in psql to check.

Answer (score 1):

You might be connecting to ambari postgres. Check hawq settings in Ambari and use 
psql -h hostname -p port -d database -U username.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps .

Login to hawq master node

ps -ef |grep silent  (Find out the port that hawq master is listening to )

su - gpadmin

psql ( psql should connect you to hawq gpadmin database )

if not type

psql -p portnumber -h masterhost  -d database